# Are layouts in nuxt.js actually useful? What are the benefits?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, layout, nuxt.js

As far as I understood, layouts only help to get rid of importing a component and having to wrap every page in a layout component. With the auto import feature you can even get rid of the import. So essentially you are only saving the need of wrapping your pages in your layout components.

Having no component and just a string (`layout: "my-layout"`)  reduces flexibility, since you can't pass props or events to the layout component from your page components.

Are there performance or any other advantages when using layouts? I think it's good practise to have a layout folder, but I don't the see a benefit of the addition of the layout prop in the Options API.

Answer (score 1):

This post in `/r/Nuxt` is pretty interesting: https://www.reddit.com/r/Nuxt/comments/iy7a9u/eli5_difference_between_components_pages_and

I'd quote some interesting replies:

> Layouts: if you have some components, which you know you want to use on several pages (like the header and footer, for example), you can just import and add these into a layout, then use this layout on the pages that require it. No need to separately import and add those mandatory components into each page separately and there's less duplication of code. Also any css definitions which should apply only to specific pages can be put in there, instead of having to add them to each page/component separately.

> Layouts are really just top level wrapper components that are really helpful to keep a lot of the boilerplate code in one spot instead of inserting it into each page. For instance, I could have a blog layout with a sidebar on the right, breadcrumbs on top and a widget on the left. I would create a "blog.vue" so that I can keep my pages DRY.

TLDR: you should use `Layouts` as the top level wrappers to keep things DRY. They are not supposed to have any props from `Pages` because they are wrapping them. Of course, a component could also make the job on this regard but it's a bit more verbose.
There is no performance benefit IMO (everything is a component), meanwhile `Layouts` are more semantic.

Comment: It enforces a convention, which is what nuxt is quite good at. I don't think that layouts shouldn't be able to have props or events. Maybe there is a button in the navigation in which each page wants to react differently. A Save-Button? At the end it boils down to preference. I'd much rather be explicit  and use the layout component as a normal vue component for such trivial cases rather than relying on a convention with a string. If it would do more than just rendering a component I would reconsider my opinion.

Comment: Since it should be above pages, it is kinda global so, you usually do use vuex to handle any reactivity in the layout. I do only have a few in my project and there have a lot of nested pages/components but this is my entry point so far and I don't nest several layouts (usually), only one at a time.

Comment: Thats debatable for sure. Still it's an overkill to me. I have no advantage of having a string instead of a component. Conventions are good, but I would keep them as minimal as possible and only if they solve problems on a much easier and cleaner way, like the routing with folders. Every convention adds complexity, one should keep that in mind.