# Import / export Nuxt layouts

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm on Nuxtjs 2.15.4 and I wanna import my layouts from different directories.
for example

```js
import cms from '~~/mylayout/cms.vue' 
export default{
  layout: cms
}
```

how can I achieve that?? the important thing is that my layouts be able to import by `import` function.

I'm doing this for dynamic themes, so that i can read layouts from different directories.

And, how can I change the default layout name?? As I wanna implement dynamic layouts, I probable need to import default layout too. so where I can tell Nuxt that for example `~~/mylayout/d.vue` is my default layout?

Comment: not answer itself , but the comments bellow that, absolutely!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to import the layout, it is done for you. Simply put it in the `layouts` directory.

Comment: I know that. how can i work on Nuxt without that minimum knowledge !! :D  . As I said I'm working on theming my app. so I need to tell nuxt that read from another folder instead of layout. you will get what I'm gonna achieve if you read this: https://adrianjost.medium.com/nuxt-js-theming-1-18e9caa1dfd9

Comment: You could achieve it with the `dir` property: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/nuxt-config/#dir Give it, `layouts: my_cool_layouts`.

Comment: actually knew about that too :) . and that's not gonna help me. let me explain a bit. that option completely change my directory, yeah but I want it too be like this: read from my theme directory; if not exist, read from core directory. I can do this by changing aliases, but I need `import leyout from '~mydir/layout'` expression to do that. Btw do you know how to change default layout?

Comment: You cannot have dynamic layouts and it's not really supposed to be IMO. If you have something dynamic, create a component and use a `<component :is="myFancyComponent>your wrapped content</component>` dynamic component: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#keep-alive-with-Dynamic-Components The end result is the same, you only need to wrap your template inside of it. If it's just colors that are changed, you don't even need layouts nor components, changing the colors in CSS should be enough.

Comment: I thought of making each layout a component and do my layout staff in theme too. wont it cause performance issue!? because it has to load an extra components

Comment: It should be good. The performance is a broad subject. Will using components be worse than layouts? No. Will your whole thing be performant? No way to say.

Comment: This question was pretty interesting, give it a look: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67700165/8816585